# Simple Shopping Cart

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I have 2 drop down boxes to select products and a div for a shopping cart.

```
<select id="RAM">
  <option value="1">4 GB</option>
  <option value="2">8 GB</option>
</select>

<select id="HDD">
  <option value="1">300 GB</option>
  <option value="2">500 GB</option>
</select>

<ul id="cart">
  <li>PRODUCT NAME (PRICE)</li>
  <li>PRODUCT NAME (PRICE)</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to pass this dropdown value to a PHP file using AJAX and return product name & Product price etc, to `#cart` as a `<li>` with out refreshing page. and also without repeating the same product. Please suggest me a good/secure way to do this.

- Client can always change what he choose Ex: 4 GB RAM to a 8GB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, create form:

```
<form id="form">
  <select name="RAM">
    <option value="0">4 GB</option>
    <option value="1">8 GB</option>
  </select>

  <select name="HDD">
    <option value="0">300 GB</option>
    <option value="1">500 GB</option>
  </select>
</form>

<ul id="cart">
  <li>PRODUCT NAME (PRICE)</li>
  <li>PRODUCT NAME (PRICE)</li>
</ul>
```

And ajax code (I use jQuery library because of its compatibility with all browsers):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#form').change(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'script.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#cart').empty();
                    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                        var $li = $('<li></li>')
                            .text(value['product'] + ' (price: ' + value['price'] + ')')
                            .appendTo($('#cart'));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Now you have to write PHP script:

```
<?php

$prices = array(
    'HDD' => array(30, 50),
    'RAM' => array(100, 200)
);

$data = array();
foreach ($_POST as $product => $index)
    $data[] = array('product' => $product, 'price' => $prices[$product][$index]);

print json_encode($data);
exit;
```

I think you want to save users choices. If I'm right, add saving products to cookies or database.
Cookie example:

```
setcookie('cart',$data,time()+24*3600*5,'/'); // save cookie for 5 days
```

I hope it is useful for you :)

Comment: I tried this one. but it returns [] as a respond. still couldn't find whats wrong... :/

Comment: nope. Everything same as your reply... Parameters also passing correctly. but php returns []

Comment: Sorry, my fault... I haven't checked code before I sending. It has some mistakes. Now code is correct (I changed only JavaScript listing).

Comment: Now working 100% correctly. Thanks for the help man, hey I have another problem. If client want's just only a RAM what can we do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery get or post for the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) and [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

---

### Example:

```
$('#RAM').change(function() {
    var value = $('#RAM option:selected').text();
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: 'POST', // Request method
        url: 'yourFile.php?value='+ value, // URL
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(result)
        {
            // do something here when PHP return result (or nothing?)
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @GeoPhoenix `val()` will return '1' or '2' (value attribute), while `text()` will return '4 GB' or '8 GB'. It depends on you, you can choose any of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#RAM').change(function() {
    var value = $('#RAM').val();
    $.ajax(
    {
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'service.php?value='+ value,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response)
    {
       $('#price').html(response.price);
       $('#name').html(response.name);
    }
    });
});
```